# How to pool AWS SQS with AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

At the moment I'm are pooling AWS SQS from our back-end and doing business logic once payload is received.

I would like to move this to AWS Lambda and start automating business logic via SQS/SNS.

As I can not subscribe to AWS SQS events, what is the best practice in implementing SQS pooling with Lambda (node.js)?

Comment: If you're already using SNS use that to trigger lambda. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda.html

Comment: Ask is not clear. Add clarifying details. Lambda can be triggered on a SQS.

Answer (score 1):

SQS doesn't really work well with Lambda since you cannot automatically trigger Lambda functions from SQS queues messages.

I would rather remove the SQS/SNS logic and go for a DynamoDB Streams based solution that would cover the queueing, archiving & Lambda triggering tasks natively: your producer puts messages in a DynamoDB table while your Lambda is triggered for any new entry with Streams (it's an [AWS native mechanism](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html))

Of course a Kinesis based solution may be considered as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to even simplify the whole polling process by using the built-in SQS event source for lambda.

> Lambda will automatically scale out horizontally consume the messages
>   in my queue. Lambda will try to consume the queue as quickly and
>   effeciently as possible by maximizing concurrency within the bounds of
>   each service. As the queue traffic fluctuates the Lambda service will
>   scale the polling operations up and down based on the number of
>   inflight messages.

see [AWS Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-adds-amazon-simple-queue-service-to-supported-event-sources/)

Answer (score 0):

> As I can not subscribe to AWS SQS events,

Why?

Lambda can be triggered on SQS messages. Lambda internally handles the scaling, batching and retries for you. Check [this AWS documentation on how to use Lambda with SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html).